# awk/sed: Delete rest of line after second match

Tags: sed, awk

I need some help deleting the rest of the line after (and including) the second match of line 1 (and only line 1) in some files. For example if pattern would be an asterisk `*`:

Input:

```
asd*asd*asd*asd*asd*
asdasdasd*asdasdasd*asdasdasd*asdasdasd
```

Expected output:

```
asd*asd
asdasdasd*asdasdasd*asdasdasd*asdasdasd
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "*" } 
    FNR == 1 { 
        print $1, $2 
    } 
    FNR > 1 { 
        print 
    }
' infile
```

That yields:

```
asd*asd
asdasdasd*asdasdasd*asdasdasd*asdasdasd
```

Answer (score 2):

To limit the operation to a line, use an "Address":

```
sed '1s/\([^*]\*[^*]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks! it works great. I'm just afraid my example does not represent well my data. What if I would want to the pattern to be a tab?
Somehow, when I replace the asterisks inside the square brackets with \t it does not work... sed '1s/\([^\t]\*[^\t]*\).*/\1/'

Comment: `sed` is not able to represent a tab. You can use bash's quoting to help it: `sed $'1s/\([^\t]\t[^\t]*\).*/\\1/'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1s/\*[^*]*//2g' file
```

Comment: Note: using `2g` produces unspecified behavior, so don't rely on this with other implementations of sed.

Comment: N.B. @WilliamPursell I do specify GNU sed.